# Scratch style shapes using CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes, clip-path

How to create shapes as shown in screenshot below with CSS. The green rectangles look easy to make, but the problems is orange one and blue one. This project is an open source project https://github.com/LLK/scratch-www, but I cannot find the code of above blocks.

Can I get some hints?

[image]

image source: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tutorial=getStarted

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: With a straight tag, you wont be able too. CSS is not really designed for complex shapes. People have done some pretty impressive stuff with it, but not really practical for most uses. There often ends up with multiple nested divs etc. SVG is probably your best option. SVG is what scratch uses. Use the browser developer tools to inspect the elements and you can see exactly how they do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### method 1: Using svg

```css
body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#dfdfdf 2%, transparent 6%);
  background-position: 0 0, 100px 100px;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.svg-shape {
  position: relative;
}

.svg-shape span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-shape">
  <span>move 10 steps</span>
  <svg>
 <path class="blocklyPath blocklyBlockBackground" stroke="#3373CC" fill="#4C97FF" fill-opacity="1" d="m 0,4 A 4,4 0 0,1 4,0 H 12 c 2,0 3,1 4,2 l 4,4 c 1,1 2,2 4,2 h 12 c 2,0 3,-1 4,-2 l 4,-4 c 1,-1 2,-2 4,-2 H 145.3670997619629 a 4,4 0 0,1 4,4 v 40  a 4,4 0 0,1 -4,4 H 48   c -2,0 -3,1 -4,2 l -4,4 c -1,1 -2,2 -4,2 h -12 c -2,0 -3,-1 -4,-2 l -4,-4 c -1,-1 -2,-2 -4,-2 H 4 a 4,4 0 0,1 -4,-4 z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

### method 2: Using CSS clip-path

You can also create it using css [clip-path](/questions/tagged/clip-path) property, which has limited [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), but you have to play around a bit to get it perfect.

> The clip-path property allows you to make complex shapes in CSS by
>   clipping an element to a basic shape (circle, ellipse, polygon, or
>   inset), or to an SVG source.

I have used https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ to create clip path quickly.

```css
body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#dfdfdf 2%, transparent 6%);
  background-position: 0 0, 100px 100px;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}

.shape-blue {
  position: relative;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  background: #4274c6;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon( 9% 27%, 22% 27%, 26% 35%, 44% 34%, 48% 25%, 94% 25%, 94% 50%, 50% 50%, 44% 60%, 25% 60%, 20% 51%, 9% 51%);
  clip-path: polygon( 9% 27%, 22% 27%, 26% 35%, 44% 34%, 48% 25%, 94% 25%, 94% 50%, 50% 50%, 44% 60%, 25% 60%, 20% 51%, 9% 51%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 108px;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-style: 1rem;
}

.text span {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: #585e73;
  border: 1px solid #585e73;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.shape-blue:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 279px;
  width: 279px;
  background-color: #5d98f7;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon( 9% 27%, 22% 27%, 26% 35%, 44% 34%, 48% 25%, 94% 25%, 94% 50%, 50% 50%, 44% 60%, 25% 60%, 20% 51%, 9% 51%);
  clip-path: polygon( 9% 27%, 22% 27%, 26% 35%, 44% 34%, 48% 25%, 94% 25%, 94% 50%, 50% 50%, 44% 60%, 25% 60%, 20% 51%, 9% 51%);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-blue">
  <div class="text">
    move <span>10</span> steps
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: everything possible with css just what we have to take care is browser support as per our requirement. Good Job @eirenaios

Comment: @Juntae I will improve the shape properly and update the answer soon, right now its just roughly created

Comment: @Juntae added svg method, it is short and simple to implement

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is you don't.

CSS is not well suited to these kind of shapes. Scratch uses [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web) . I've copy and pasted the [path](/questions/tagged/path) tag below direct from Scratch

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     width="300" height="200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path class="blocklyPath blocklyBlockBackground" stroke="#3373CC" fill="#4C97FF" fill-opacity="1" d="m 0,4 A 4,4 0 0,1 4,0 H 12 c 2,0 3,1 4,2 l 4,4 c 1,1 2,2 4,2 h 12 c 2,0 3,-1 4,-2 l 4,-4 c 1,-1 2,-2 4,-2 H 145.3670997619629 a 4,4 0 0,1 4,4 v 40  a 4,4 0 0,1 -4,4 H 48   c -2,0 -3,1 -4,2 l -4,4 c -1,1 -2,2 -4,2 h -12 c -2,0 -3,-1 -4,-2 l -4,-4 c -1,-1 -2,-2 -4,-2 H 4 a 4,4 0 0,1 -4,-4 z"></path>
</svg>
```

**Note** how did I find this you ask? I used the browser developer tools (F12 in most browsers) to inspect the element. That took me directly to the [path](/questions/tagged/path) tag I included.